# fix broken pipe with zsh

Tags: linux, pipe, zsh, oh-my-zsh

As suggested here https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30184/10-ways-to-generate-a-random-password-from-the-command-line/ , I'm trying to generate random password with the following command :

```
< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c${1:-32};echo;
```

This works smooth in a *bash* shell, but gives the following warning/error message on *zsh* :

> a8vuFvMzDcV4E-vbbkvfgi1Gf3KYtYiC[1]    40491 broken pipe  tr -dc
> _A-Z-a-z-0-9 < /dev/urandom |
> 40492 done         head -c${1:-32}

What could be the origin of this message and how could we adapt this to make it work on *zsh* ?

Comment: I don't think the issue is `zsh`.  It looks like in one instance `tr` is emitting an error message, while it's not in the other.  Try `which tr` in both shells.

Comment: For both *zsh* and *bash* `which tr` give me `/usr/bin/tr`

Comment: It's on Ubuntu 20.04, `/usr/bin/tr` is installed from *coreutils* 8.30-3ubuntu2

Comment: The `40491` and the `40492 done` suggest that you're running something in the background.  Can you demonstrate a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I've got it ... since no one seems to get the same as I do, I run in a VM with a zsh from scratch. The output comes from zsh's option (which is important for my daily job) `setopt PRINT_EXIT_VALUE`. When this is set, I get the error message, when not, I don't get it.

Comment: and no @WilliamPursell, I haven't jobs in the background. `jobs` certifies it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the zsh mailing list https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2021/msg01171.html , this is the expected behavior when using the option `setopt PRINT_EXIT_VALUE`.

The solution to keep that option set, but not for that single command is to run it in a subshell as :

```
( < /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c 32; echo )
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say, as it works perfectly for me on bash and zsh on two of my work-stations.

Probably it's not a so big deal as the problem that 1st process (urandom...) produce unlimited output that is written to 2nd process : "head -c${1:-32};echo;"

At the moment that the second process is over, the first still continue to write into the pipe and so give an error (as the pipe is closed by 2nd process).

It's explained better here :

https://superuser.com/questions/554855/how-can-i-fix-a-broken-pipe-error

There is also a solution in the same url, something like :

```
< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | tail -n +1 | head -c${1:-32};echo;
```

But I could not check it as for me it works already well.
Could you give a try ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your suggest command doesn't work either.

Comment: I tried to disable oh-my-zsh things and open a new terminal ... still the same.

Comment: Hmmm... strange things. By the way, I think you command works, even at zsh. In your example "a8vuFvMzDcV4E-vbbkvfgi1Gf3KYtYiC" is the generated password. So I said I think your command works, but just give some messages about pipe closed too fast.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the output is the expected random data + unexpected error msg about a broken pipe

Comment: @PaulZahkarov : I can reproduce the OPs problem (zsh version 5.8, running under Cygwin), and also the fact that the behaviour depends on the setting of PRINT_EXIT_VALUE.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to use `head` to read /dev/urandom instead of `tr`, like so :

```
< /dev/urandom head -c 1000 | tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c 32; echo;
```

But there is no guarantee that I'll get a 32 chars random sequence. And increasing 1000 to 100000 leads to broken pipe again.